# How do you list every letter from a-z in jstl

Tags: java, jstl

Using jstl I want to list each letter of the alphabet.

I want something like
a
b
...
z

Comment: In Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578233/how-do-i-get-the-set-of-all-letters-in-java-clojure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, no scriptlet. How about a JSP expression? If you don't want either of them, then you can create a custom EL function. Look near bottom of  [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  
<c:forEach var="i" begin="97" end="122">
    <%=Character.toChars((Integer)pageContext.getAttribute("i"))%>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<c:set var="alphabet" value="A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z" />
<c:forTokens var="letter" items="${alphabet}" delims=",">
    ${letter}
</c:forTokens>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can inject java directly in (I don't know JSTL) you could do this

```
for(char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
    System.out.println(letter + " ");
}
```

keeping in mind that a `char` is just an unsigned integer.

Comment: I am not allowed to inject Java scriptlets directly in the code.  I'm not saying it is a reasonable restriction, but it is the restriction I am working under.