# Increment letter in JSTL/EL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, jsp-tags

So I am doing something like this for numbers:

```
<c:set var="n" value="${n+1}"/>
```

Is there an equivalent for incrementing a letter? If 'a', then set as 'b', if 'd' then set as 'e' ? Something like:

```
<c:set var="c" value="${c++}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876955) seems to have it. I would suggest using a scriptlet to get it done. This will let you execute and embed simple java function calls in your JSP

```
<c:set var="c" value="<%=Character.toChars( ## int value of c++ ##)%>"/>
```